# pgfplots 1.9 on Mac

Tags: pgfplots, texlive

I have an iMac with TeX Live 2011. It came with `pgfplots` version 1.4, which I am able to use without a problem. I just downloaded `pgfplots` version 1.9 which has new environments like polar axis, smith chart, etc., which I like to use.

How can I install downloaded package of `pgfplots` 1.9 on my iMac? Can I place it in `texlive/2011/texmf-var`? Should I do anything after that? Also I have TeXShop for editing my TeX files. My OS is 10.6.8.

Kindly help.

Comment: If you don't have bandwidth constraints, it would be better to install [TeX live 2013](http://www.tug.org/mactex/). That way you have an up-to-date system, and don't need to care about package dependencies etc.

Comment: I dont' think you can safely install `pgfplots` 1.9 without also updating the whole TikZ/PGF subsystem and possibly several other packages. Mac OS X 10.6.8 can run TeX Live 2013, so the best advice is to update the whole MacTeX distribution.

Comment: OK, I will install Tex live 2013. Thank you both.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is resolved by installing a newer TeX distro.